# Getting an error in the XML schema

Tags: xml

I keep getting the error: Attribute name "element" associated with an element type "xs" must be followed by the ' = ' character. on Line 4 whenever I validate my XML schema, also as you can see in my XML schema and my XML document I have 2 item tags have I done the right thing for them in the XML schema, I am new to this, in fact my first time trying XML schema today

XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

<xs element name="shiporder" type="xs:string">
<xs: complexType>
<xs: sequence>
<xs element name="orderperson"/>
<xs element name="shipto">
<xs: complexType>
<xs: sequence>
<xs element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
<xs element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
<xs element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
<xs: complexType>
<xs: sequence>
<xs: element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
<xs: element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
<xs: element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs: element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="item" type="xs:string" use="required"/> 
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<shiporder orderid="889923" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd"> 
<orderperson>John Smith</orderperson> 
<shipto> 
<name>Ola Nordmann</name> 
<address>Langgt 23</address> 
<city>4000 Stavanger</city> 
<country>Norway</country> 
</shipto> 
<item> 
<title>Empire Burlesque</title> 
<note>Special Edition</note> 
<quantity>1</quantity> 
<price>10.90</price> 
</item> 
<item> 
<title>Hide your heart</title> 
<quantity>1</quantity> 
<price>9.90</price> 
</item> 
</shiporder>
```

Comment: Is that really your code? Besides the missing colons, there seem to be many more problems. It's not well-formed XML. Please check your sources and post the actual files you are having trouble with. And please format the code.

Comment: that is my code, hence why I am trying to fix my code, so i can learn from my code

Comment: Yes, but you should at least post the full XML Schema and format it.

Comment: that is the full xml schema, its my first day, its the day you are meant to make mistakes

Comment: Yes. It's OK to make mistakes. You only learn by doing so. But formatting the code makes it easier for you and those who try to answer the question. If you indent the code you will also discover some problems by yourself, like the absence of a closing `</xs:schema>` tag, for example. Writing a good question is also a very efficient way of learning. This is good advice: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: did indent it, but stackoverflow was not reading it as a code

Comment: Try selecting the full code, and then click on the `{}` icon. It will preserve the code between `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to replace `<xs element` with `<xs:element` in the schema. Since otherwise `element` is indeed not interpreted as a *tagname*, but as an *attribute*.

Furthermore you need to fold your element and complexType into one tag:

So:

```
<xs element name="shiporder" type="xs:string">
<xs: complexType>
```

Should become:

```
<xs: complexType name="shiporder">
```

Don't forget to remove the closing tags as well (since there is only one begin tag after this operation).

And you need to drop the type (otherwise you cannot insert data into the tag).

Comment: no now it says Not well formed: Attribute name "complexType" associated with an element type "xs:" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Comment: Have you tried it using a colon? Most schema's I have seen at least use the colon (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256129%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: its okay, I fixed it, was the spaces and elements were missing :